# Is this inheritance, and if not what is it?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

So, I've always learned that inheritance is about extending existing classes in Java and Python. This involves calling the constructor of the parent class through `super` in Python, or `extends` in Java.

Today, I wanted to make a custom implementation of `scikit-learn`'s `OneHotEncoder` object that just works on strings. It encodes them to sparse vectors or decodes sparse vectors back to strings:

```
ALL_LETTERS = string.ascii_letters + ".,;'"
ALL_LETTERS_ARRAY = np.array(list(ALL_LETTERS))

class WordEncoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit(ALL_LETTERS_ARRAY.reshape(-1, 1))

    def transform(self, word):
        word = np.array(list(word)).reshape(-1, 1)
        return self.encoder.transform(word)

    def inverse_transform(self, X):
        word_arr = self.encoder.inverse_transform(X).reshape(-1,)
        return ''.join(word_arr)
```

So, this class doesn't inherit all of the `OneHotEncoder` class attributes or methods.

Is this good OOP design? I often see the word "wrapper" in various docs, is that what this is? So yeah, just trying to write good, clean code and wondering all these things.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here... "So, this class doesn't inherit all of the" there is no inheritance here, it doesn't inherit *any* `OneHotEncoder` attributes/methods. This is composition. That's fine, if that's what you are asking. There are people of the opinion that you should *never* use inheritance and just stick with composition.

Comment: I was asking if this counts as inheritance (I thought the title was clear, sorry). I was also asking what this is called if not inheritance, and whether it's good practice. I will clarify the question even though someone else correctly interpreted it and answered it.

Comment: OK, then no, this isn't inheritance. Inheritance from `OneHotEncoder` would require something like `class MyEncoder(OneHotEncoder): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that WordEncoder *has* a OneHotEncoder instance, I would say what you have done is an example of composition, rather than inheritance. And your design is perfectly fine. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) article may be useful for understanding the difference between inheritance and composition.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Reading the article now.